# Setting up Nginx proxy, trying to pass users browser traffic for google, looks good; but for openai.com: got 502 Bad Gateway.. Why?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Because in my country, cannot access some websites, like google.com, openai.com, and some others. These are blocked.

So now I am trying to setup a proxy based on my domain using Nginx. My custom domain is setup in a VM from which can access these websites.

What excepted: when users input domain such as https://google.yesky.online, will be pass to google.com, when users input https://openai.yesky.online, will be pass to openai.com.

Below is my nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name google.yesky.online;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
        proxy_set_header Host www.google.com;
        proxy_set_header Referer https://www.google.com;

        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        sub_filter www.google.com google.yesky.online;
        sub_filter_once off;

    }
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name openai.yesky.online;
 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
 
 
 
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://openai.com;
        proxy_set_header Host openai.com;
        proxy_set_header Referer https://openai.com;
 
        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 
        sub_filter openai.com yesky.online;
        sub_filter_once off;

    }
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name platform.yesky.online;
 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
 
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://platform.openai.com;
        proxy_set_header Host platform.openai.com;
        proxy_set_header Referer https://platform.openai.com;
 
        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        sub_filter openai.com yesky.online;
        sub_filter_once off;

    }
}






server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name chat.yesky.online;
 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yesky.online/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
 
 
 
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://chat.openai.com;
        proxy_set_header Host chat.openai.com;
        proxy_set_header Referer https://chat.openai.com;
 
        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 
        sub_filter openai.com yesky.online;
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
}
```

For google.com, it looks good.
[image]

For openai.com, alredy setup 3 domain/sub domain: openai.com, chat.openai.com, and platform.openai.com.
When browser its home page openai.com(https://openai.yesky.online), looks good.
[image]

But when click [Log in], trying to open platform.openai.com, got error: 502 Bad Gateway;
[image]
When click [TryChatGPT], trying to open chat.openai.com, got error: 502 Bad Gateway;
[image]

Trying to find any clue...

Nginx error log: /var/log/nginx/error.log
[image]

What does this error mean?
Any comments are welcome.